# where can I find planned spring boot release dates

Tags: spring-boot

I use Springboot 2.1.x and 2.2.x ,the last releases were in end Oct 2020. Where can I find the planned next release dates for the same - particularly springboot 2.1.19 and 2.2.12 ?

Comment: look here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/milestones, usually the milestone due dates are not far off the release dates

Answer (score 10):

Here's a calendar of planned Spring releases:

https://calendar.spring.io/